# Memory/RAM usage on different devices with same app

Tags: android, memory, ram, device

I made an android game with cocos2d-android.

When I test this game on different devices, the RAM usage is varied:

**Samsung Galaxy Note (2.3.5):**

- Task-Manager show: about 17MB
- Watchdog: about 23MB
- Debug: about 10MB (Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1048576L)

**Samsung Galaxy I9000 (2.3.3):**

- Task-Manager: about 55MB
- Watchdog: about 42MB
- Debug: about 25MB

**Emulator (2.3.3 && 3.2):**

- Debug: about 40MB

I don't have a clue why the memory consumption on different devices of the same game is varied like this. Has anybody an answer?

Comment: how different are the heap sizes? Java will clear memory only when it deems necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of those devices are running a different version of Android, and are likely running different types of software in the background.

If your not experiencing any problems, and your users aren't complaining - I dont see anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy I9000 has a heap size of 64MB. Galaxy Note has a heap size of 128MB. In the emulator a heap size of 24MB is default but of course you can choose any size.

I am still don't know exactly why the ram usage is that much different, but it seems to have something to do with the bitmaps I use for the game. In the newest version I added low resolution bitmaps for low-end devices. If I turn on the low resolution bitmaps on the I9000 the ram usage is decreasing strongly. If I start the game with low-resolution bitmaps on the galaxy note the ram usage decrease is much smaller, nonetheless the game works smooth on both devices with sd and hd graphics and the user feedback in the android market is positive too.